# UINavigationController - clear background using UIBlurEffect

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uinavigationcontroller, uiblureffect

I am using `UIBlurEffect` in a `UIViewController` which is presented with a `.crossDissolve` transition style. The UIViewController has a collectionView added to its view so both have a clear background.

`HomeViewController.swift`

```
func showLiveDealsCategory(sender:UITextField){
    let catSelection = LiveDealCategorySelection()
    //let navContr = UINavigationController(rootViewController: catSelection)
    catSelection.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
    catSelection.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
    self.present(catSelection, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

`LiveDealCategorySelection.swift`

```
func setupBackgroundView(){
    if !UIAccessibilityIsReduceTransparencyEnabled() {
        self.view.backgroundColor = .clear
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.dark)
        let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        blurEffectView.frame = (self.view?.bounds)!
        blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        self.view?.addSubview(blurEffectView)
    } else {
        self.collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    }
}
```

This is the result where you can see the mapView behind `LiveDealCategorySelection`:

[image]

The problem is when I embed the view controller inside a `UINavigationController` because I am not able to set its background color to `.clear`:

```
func showLiveDealsCategory(sender:UITextField){
        let catSelection = LiveDealCategorySelection()
        let navContr = UINavigationController(rootViewController: catSelection)
        catSelection.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
        catSelection.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
        self.present(navContr, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

In `LiveDealCategorySelection` I tried:

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if self.navigationController != nil {
            self.navigationController!.view.backgroundColor = .clear
            self.navigationController!.view.tintColor = .clear
        }
  }
```

and I also tried to set the background color to `.clear` when I instantiate the navigation controller but I get a black background. Any idea?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just forgot to move the presentation style to the UINavigationController

```
navContr.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
```

Comment: unfortunately it's not working either. Apparantly `.clear` background cannot be used with `UINavigationController`

Comment: Have a pretty similar code that you posted which includes the `.clear` on `UINavigationController`, just without the CollectionView, running on iOS10.2 on both simulator and device.

Comment: [Blurred Background](https://gist.github.com/MarioBajr/75e485e5082445183f7b42f7b91182f8)

Answer (score 0):

With navigation controller you cannot achieve that you want. Only Modal presentation with OverCurrentContext, supports transition from one view controller to another with clear or semi transparent background.

If you want blur background for this view controller then present this view controller using modal presentation with 'custom (or over current context)'

else try this:

```
func showLiveDealsCategory(sender:UITextField){
        let catSelection = LiveDealCategorySelection()
        let navContr = UINavigationController(rootViewController: catSelection)
        navContr.modalPresentationStyle = .custom  // << Mark this update
        catSelection.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
        catSelection.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
        self.present(navContr, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate a little bit. Do you mean that I can present the navigationController using `.overCurrentContext` and that would support clear background?

Comment: Not navigation controller but your view controller only.

e.g. from ViewController1 

let viewController2 = storyboard.instantiateViewcontrollerWithIndentier as? ViewController2
viewcontroller.modalpresentation = .overcurrentcontext
self.present(viewcontroller2, animated: true)

Comment: It  was already working using the viewController in the code shown above. Using `.custom` instead of `.overCurrentContext`

Comment: So, you want if from Navigation controller only?

Comment: Unfortunately I need a navigationController there,  leaving the transparent background.